# ParseExact DateTime exception

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse this date string but it's giving a format exception which is driving me crazy. Can anyone help?

```
string date = "05032013123020";
string format = "ddMMyyyyHHmmss";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, null);
```

Comment: What is that character at the start of the string?!

Comment: Why edit out the character at the start of the string? It might be a valid character in the OP string and therefore is what is causing the problem.

Comment: I didn't edit the string at all, even though it shows up in the revision too. I only removed the [C#] tag from the title.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Don't know why the edit removed it then :P Just thinking this could of potentially been the problem, until the OP states it was a typo anyway

Comment: @LukeHennerley Yes, strange. I'll post this to Meta. Maybe I've discovered some bug :P

Comment: your code as it is above works for me - get a DateTime of 05/03/2013 12:30:20

Comment: Looking at the revision history, I can see that there is (was) a non-printable ascii character (ascii code 31) in your `date` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pasted *string date = "05032013123020";* to Notepad++ you can see the following result:

string date = "US05032013123020";

That's why you are getting an error at parsing